# E-R model to relational database with one entity twice in one relationship

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

I am trying as an exercise for an exam to transfer a database from the ER model to a relational database.
However, I am very unsure whether my solution makes sense. In particular, the two relationships between `location` and `has` makes great problems. I thought I could add one ZipCode as a regular primary key into the table has and a second ZipCode as foreign key. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.
[image: The ERM]

My Solution so far:

[image: Relational database]

Answer (score 1):

If you are following Chen ER design with this Chen ER diagram then you need a table for every entity type box and every relationship (association) type diamond and a FK (foreign key) for every participation/role line for a relationship type.

(It is a bad idea to call lines/FKs "relationships" or "associations" in a Chen context because diamonds/tables represent relationship types and lines/FKs represent participations.)

So your `Ship tourID` would be dropped in favour of relationship/table `takes` with lines/FKs to `Ship` & `Tour`. And you would have two FKs in the `has` table to `Location`. It doesn't matter that you need different column names in the relationship table than in the participant table. A FK just says the values in some table & column list appear in some other table & column list. The diagram says the names are `start` & `target`; use them.

Don't use a flaccid uninformative name like `has`. If you picked a better name and/or explained when a triplet of entities satisfied the `has` relationship then we could know what reasonable designs would be. Eg you may not be using cardinalities correctly. The Chen way is, a number or range tells for some instance of the entity type how many relationship instances it can participate in. Another way is, a number or range tells you for a some combination of entity instances of the *other* participating entity types how many instances of the line's entity type can participate with it. If the latter has a zero that means a relationship instance can have a NULL. But that can't arise in a Chen design; participating entity instance combinations identify relationship instances and form PKs (primary keys).

However, a Chen design can't express all relational designs. And we can represent the same data as a Chen ER schema by rearranging tables. Eg dropping binary relationship tables that are not many:many and putting FKs (sometimes nullable) into entity tables instead, just as you did with `takes`, `Ship` & `Tour`. Some methods have non-Chen diagrams expressing such designs directly. Others allow it in the move from Chen diagram to schema. You have to ask your teachers whether they care just what variations from the Chen style of ER diagrams and corresponding schemas you are permitted to make.

(It is this dropping in non-Chen methods of explicit 1:many relationships/associations and their representation by FKs that leads to FKs being incorrectly (but commonly) called "relationships" or "associations".)